# Issue sending a JSON object to Stripe

Tags: node.js, http, next.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to send a JSON Object to Stripe, but I am always receiving an error from the response.

API resolved without sending a response for /api/ctrlpnl/products_submit, this may result in stalled requests.
{
error: {
code: 'parameter_unknown',
doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown',
message: 'Received unknown parameter: {"name":"dasdas"}',
param: '{"name":"dasdas"}',
type: 'invalid_request_error'
}
}

My code is below:

```
 import Stripe from 'stripe';
 import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

 const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
     apiVersion: '2020-08-27'
 });

 export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

   if (req.method === 'POST') {
     try {   
       const name = { name: req.body.name };

       fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/v1/products`, {
    
         method: 'POST',
         body: JSON.stringify(name),
         headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             "content-type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`,
         }
         }).then((response) => {
             return response.json();
         }).then(data => {
             console.log(data);
             res.status(200).json(data)
         })

 } catch (err) {
     res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
 }
  } else {
     res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
     res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
 }
 }
```

Comment: If you are anyway importing the stripe package, why are you creating the post request by hand and not using the sdk? `stripe.products.create(...)`

Comment: Thank you Patrick for message.
Will need to convert this to stripe.create products perhaps.
But the reason why I am asking is, I would like to get this solved for the training purposes.
Generally I wish this to solve, so in the future if I need to send the data in JSON format, I could achieve this, and I do not need to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content-type` of the `fetch` is correctly set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but the `body` contains a json. So Stripe is unable to parse the `body` parameters.

To fix that, you need to replace `JSON.stringify` by `new URLSearchParams`:

```
const name = { name: req.body.name };

fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/v1/products`, { 
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams(name), // ← this will return "name=xxxx"
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`,
    }
});
```

Note that I recommend using [the Stripe library](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create?lang=node) which is much simpler to use: `stripe.products.create(name);`, especially since you already included it in your code.